# Android Woes....Why no socket exception? Work around?

Tags: android, sockets

I have a socket connection thread using objectinput and output stream to read and write objects across the socket.

In Android 2.1 update and 2.2.1, whenever you call a `socket.shutdownOutput()`, it throws an exception in the connection thread, I catch it and do a finally for a a cleanup. For some funny reason `socket.close()` does not throw an exception in the versions mentioned either.

In 2.2.2, this is not the case. Calling `shutdownOutput()`, `shutdownInput()`, `close()` all do not throw any exceptions at all, and I have to wait until the socket timeout is called before I can do any cleanups.

Can anyone shed some light on what is happening? A workaround solution would be nice too.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Maurice, it sounds odd to me. could you share some code with us?

Comment: socket.close on your side, or the other side of the connection?  If it's on your side, why don't you just do the cleanup then? :)

Comment: A little bit hard to put the code...Basically you know when you do multiple threads for socket connection?
When you close your client connection, you do it by calling a socket.close() so that it exits the reading while loop, your typical in.readObject() will throw an Exception.
I call the socket.shutdownOutput() or socket.close() explicitly to end the thread but doesn't work in 2.2.2.

Comment: Normaly, the `finally`-block is used for clean-up.

Comment: Ok I dug up some posts from last time regarding the issue, but the workaround does not work for 2.2.2.
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6144
and
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7933

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I dug up some posts from last time regarding the issue, but the workaround does not work for 2.2.2. code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6144 and code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7933